# Why am I getting this error using Soot operations from the Eclipse Soot plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, soot

I am trying out Soot for the first time. I followed the explanation on their website for installing the Eclipse plug-in. It seemed to download just fine. I then tried to create a Java project with a simple Java program so that I could try converting it to Jimple. However, when I try this operation or any of the other Soot operations, I keep getting an error dialog box that says, "The chosen operation is not currently available." Picture below:

[image]

I am not sure what it causing this to not work. The Java build path (pictured below) seems to contain everything that should be needed:

[image]

Has anyone worked with Soot before and encountered this issue? Any suggestions for how to mitigate this situation?

---

**Edit:** also, when I try to create a Soot example project (a simple bodyTransformer), I get a "Problem Opening Wizard" error:

[image]

Comment: Also, it would be great if someone could create a Soot tag for this and other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this error has been fixed last week. There was a deployment issue with the 2.5.0 build. When you now install revision 2.5.1 of the plugin, it should work.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, once I updated to 2.5.1, it worked fine. Thanks!